# What is the name of the design pattern used in AWT/Swing that handles events?

Tags: java, swing

I have heard that there are 2 ways that we can set the PLAF in Swing.  What is the real meaning of PLAF, and what are those 2 ways?

Comment: That question title doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLAF = Pluggable Look and Feel. Basically, the same UI can have different skins with very little work.

Check out [this site](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for a detailed description of L&F. In short, there are actually 3 ways to set up your PLAF.

1) Via command line:
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel MyApp
or
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel MyApp

2) Via swing.properties file in your java lib.
swing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel

3) Programatically with either:

```
//At the beginning of your program
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
//Another option
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
//And another
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

//Or during your program - 
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

The above link also has code examples to demonstrate how to change your look and feel.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

[Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

> Some of the most notable implementations of this pattern:
>
> - The Java Swing library makes extensive use of the observer pattern
>     for event management.

Comment: What's the real difference between Observers and standard publish subscribe?

Comment: I'd say that Observer is applied to software design situations (a software design pattern), whilst publish/subscribe is more general and refers to a messaging paradigm, that is commonly implemented in middleware.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title: [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is the design pattern that Swing employs.

PLAF is a '**P**luggable **L**ook **A**nd **F**eel'.  [Here is a reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_look_and_feel) for PLAF in Java.

The title, regarding the Event Listeners, and the PLAF are not related.  The former has to do with the processing of events - more closely associated with the **C** in MVC, while the latter is generally associated with the **V**iew aspect of MVC.

Comment: PL&F are also involved with the controller aspect, hence the F. The design is not strong.